# How to copy a specific amount of rows from one ss to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 main ss `accNo` and `output`. 
I'm trying to copy `x` amount of rows from `AccNo` to output. 
The `x` is a variable and is determined by the user, it's inputted into cell `B5` from a different ss called 'input'.
Is there a way for me to loop my code which will copy row `A1, A2, A3, A4` etc from `AccNo` to output, (starting from `A4` in output)?

I'm trying this as a macro with buttons and I'm able to do one at a time, it's just the loop I'm struggling with. I need it to loop `x` amount of times so for example. if `x = 5` I want it to copy over 5 rows of data from `accNo` to output.

```
Sub TradingAccount()

    Set accNo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AccountNo")
    Set output = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Format")
    Set input = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input")

    i = 1
    e = 4

    Do loop x amount of times = True
        accNo.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy
        output.Cells(e, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '(e,1) is A4?
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        i = i + 1
        e = e + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

the macro will copy over `x` amount of rows from one spreadsheet to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop if you're using a contiguous range.  Additionally, you're using values only, so we can make this a bit easier with a `.value = .value` such that:

```
dim cnt as long, lrd as long, src as worksheet, dst as worksheet
cnt = sheets("input").cells(5,2).value 'count of rows from B5 on input
set src = sheets("AccNo") 'source sheet
set dst = sheets("output") 'destination sheet
With dst
    lrd = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row 'lastrow of destination
    .range(.rows(lrd+1),.rows(lrd+1+cnt-1)).value = src.range(src.rows(1),src.rows(cnt)).value 'FIXED "-1" IN SRC FINAL ROW; SEE COMMENTS
end with
```

*Untested code, but should give the general idea.  Note that `cnt-1` is used, as you have a starting row (1) and you want 5 total rows (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) but adding `cnt` to starting row would get you to row 6.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the above - only issue is its copying to dst cell a26 instead a4, would you know why that is?

Comment: @NewUser342 it's currently set up to paste data below the last row (`lrd+1` for last row of the destination sheet).  This would be standard for not replacing/overwriting old data, but if you only want new data, you may want to `.ClearContents` on your sheet so you aren't trying to overwrite a 30 row range with a 5 row range.

Comment: Perfect thank you, only issue is for example, if B5 is 10 it will copy over 9 rows and leave the 10th as #N/A, why is this?

Comment: @NewUser342 just realized i `cnt-1` in both source and destination... the source should *not* have the -1... only the destination should.  that's my bad.  the value `lrd+1` is having the cnt added to it, but when adding you need to subtract `1` based on my comment in the post; for the source data, the row number is exact and should not be `-`, just `src.rows(cnt)`.